# Bootstrap.css - Background image not loading on iPhone

Tags: css

I have currently made a website using a bootstrap template and it can be found at http://apparelaid.us. It works fine on desktop, but on mobile, it does not show the background image (screenshot attached). The code can be found at https://github.com/aalap07/ApparelAid. How can I fix the code so that the image will appear properly on mobile (iPhone)?

https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2Fa99%2Fa99c5fe4-1490-4306-b9cc-98adc6ac75c4%2Fimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) within the `style.css` file that specifically change the background image of the banner. These three breakpoints (media queries) occur at 480px (line 1253), 414px (line 1321), and 384px (line 1362). In this case the image is being changed to another image that doesn't exist in the images folder, so it shows up as a blank white background.

**The solution:**
Either remove the background properties of the class `.banner` at both breakpoints so this

```
    .banner {
         background: url(../images/banner22.jpg) no-repeat -150px 0px;
         background-size: cover;
         min-height: 400px;
    }
```

becomes this

```
   .banner {
       min-height: 400px;  
   }
```

**or**

upload an image to the images folder that you would want to show when the site is viewed on a mobile device and change the background url accordingly within `style.css`